# How can I use Graphviz in an asp.net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, graphviz

I want to draw a graph on web. Many users in web suggest Graphviz to me.

How can I use Graphviz in an asp.net application? What is the Graphviz render process in web?

Answer (score 2):

You may use [QuickGraph](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/) API - C# wrapper for the GraphViz graph generator. (Code project article - [QuickGraph](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5603/QuickGraph-A-100-C-graph-library-with-Graphviz-Sup): A 100% C# graph library with Graphviz Support).

> What is the Graphviz render process in web?

Using P/Invoke methods you may render in-memory image. Have a look at [Rendering an in-memory Graphviz image with C#](http://implicitoperator.com/blog/2009/12/24/rendering-an-in-memory-graphviz-image-with-c.html) and [Graphviz C# Sample](http://implicitoperator.com/blog/2010/4/11/graphviz-c-sample.html).

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong: Graphviz Support means it creates the dot file, you still need to install graphviz and run a process transforming your dot file. (http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Visualization%20Using%20Graphviz)

Comment: That's true. Graphviz is graph layout engine.

Answer (score 1):

[This fairly new library called Graphviz.NetWrapper](https://github.com/Rubjerg/Graphviz.NetWrapper) allows you to build graphs in C# code, compute a layout using the graphviz library, and read the layout information (like positions etc) back out using C#.

To draw a graph in a webpage you could send this layout information e.g. in JSON over the web and draw using e.g. D3 JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Graphviz Dll's using Interop to do that.. 
Please see this post : http://pldineshtech.blogspot.com/2012/08/using-graphviz-library-in-net.html

Basically you will be calling this method -> Graphviz.RenderImage(), create an image and transmit it back to the client.